# KDB:What is the calculation rule of the keyword div

Tags: keyword, kdb

Today I found an interesting phenomenon about div in kdb

```
a:2 div 2.4
b:2.0 div 2.4
```

The results of a and b are different.
KDB officially explains div in this way:"Returns the greatest whole number that does not exceed x%y."
In the above example, 2%2.4=0.83333... is less than 1, but the result of a is 1.
I know I missed some knowledge, but I didn't find the relevant content, please help me, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening here is type promotion. In your first example it looks like 2.4 is getting converted to an a long int (the type of the left argument) by getting rounded down to 2.
You can see this with some other examples:

```
q)2 div 1.9 // 1.9 gets rounded to 2
1
q)2 div 1.5 // 1.5 gets rounded to 2
1
q)2 div 1.49 // 1.49 gets rounded to 1
2
```

So you can see the right argument seems to be getting rounded to the nearest long int, then that is what's used for division.

For your other example it appears to be leaving the float value unchanged because that's the type of the left argument.
This is, somewhat vaguely, alluded to here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/div/
"Except for char, byte, short, and real, (div) preserves the type of the first argument."